# Working Table with Bootstrap accordions, but glyphicon-chevrons not identified by ID, so change in tandem, not individually, as desired

Tags: php, jquery

In the following question [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207549/how-to-reference-and-animate-repeated-glyphicon-chevron-in-bootstrap-accordion-i) they gave the following answer for a similar problem that I have:

"Assuming you will only have 2 rows you could do this, otherwise I would start looking into a more generic way to pull this off (e.g. using classes and CSS rules to show one glyphicon or another one based on the "collapsed" class)."

My problem is the data from my table came from a DB and I do not know how to do it in a more generic way to solve this problem.

Any help will be appreciated, I leave you a fiddle with the desirable result working with ID, but as I said this is not desirable because  my data came from database and I can not assign an unique ID, thank you in advance:

http://jsfiddle.net/7pwg1j5f/

The jquery code used for the solution given by the user using unique ID:

```
  $('#accordion1').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
            $("#package1 i.indicator").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-up").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-down");
        });
        $('#accordion1').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
            $("#package1 i.indicator").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-up");
        });

$('#accordion2').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    $("#package2 i.indicator").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-up").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-down");
});
$('#accordion2').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    $("#package2 i.indicator").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-up");
});
```

Comment: Anyone? I am not able to find nothing on the web